# Transmission of information solely for receipt by browser environment?

Tags: javascript, security, websocket, client

As part of a thought experiment, I am attempting to ascertain whether there is any hope in a server providing a piece of data only for receipt and use by a browser environment, i.e. which could not be read by a bot crawling my site.

Clearly, if that information is sent in the source code, or indeed via any usual HTTP means, this can be picked up by a bot - so far, so simple.

But what about if the information was transmitted by the server instead as a websocket message: Wouldn't this be receivable only by some corresponding (and possibly authenticated) JavaScript in the browser environment, thus precluding its interception by a bot?

(This is based on my assumption that a bot has no client environment and is essentially a malicious server-side script calling a site over something like cURL, pretending to be a user).

Another way of phrasing this question might be: with the web implementation of websockets, is the receipt of messages always done by a client environment (i.e. JS)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer about websockets, but a sufficiently motivated attacker will find a way to emulate whatever environment you require. By loading this content through ajax, you can eliminate the casual bots. You can eliminate well behaved bots with robots.txt.

Comment: Yeah, I'm conscious a committed attacked will emulate any environment you can contrive. The only exception I could think of was web sockets, hence the question. +1, though.

Answer (score 1):

Using WebSocket makes no difference. You cannot escape the following fact: you can always write a non-browser client that looks and behaves to the server exactly as any standard browser.

I can fake: any HTTP headers (like browser vendor etc) you might read. The `origin` header doesn't help either (I can fake it). Neither does cookies. I'll read them and give it back.

You might get away by protecting your site with strong captchas, and set cookies only after the captcha was solved. That depends on the captcha being unsolvable by bots ..

Comment: Yes of course - totally agree. My question boiled down to the fact that I have never seen or heard of any means by which the server (i.e. a bot) could receive a websocket message. Indeed, the receipt of websocket messages makes sense only in a client-side, real time environment. +1 all the same.

Comment: Yep, WebSocket is not only used with HTML5/browser clients, but also with non-browser clients. This has the nice effect of having the same backend being able to drive HTML5 frontends as well as other frontends (e.g. native mobile apps).